# How does Cassandra achieve strong consistency with failed writes if there is no rollback and no two phase commit?

Tags: cassandra

Looking for concrete evidence (documentation or source code) on the behavior of cassandra 3.0+ on the following situation

Write of key1, value1 is requested with consistency level of QUORUM but only N replica responded success where N < QUORUM

What happen to those N nodes that just updated key1? Do they get rollback?

In cassandra documentation
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlTransactionsDiffer.html

> if using a write consistency level of QUORUM with a replication factor of 3, Cassandra will replicate the write to all nodes in the cluster and wait for acknowledgement from two nodes. If the write fails on one of the nodes but succeeds on the other, Cassandra reports a failure to replicate the write on that node. However, the replicated write that succeeds on the other node is not automatically rolled back.

It mentions if some write failed and did not satisfied consistency level, coordinator will return failure, but the data will persist on nodes that have write succeeded

But this means strong consistency can never be achieved even if R + W > number of replica as official. documentation suggested

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDataConsistency.html

Consider the following situation

```
replica number = 5
consistency level write = 3
consistency level read = 3
```

If a write is attempted , but one nodes succeeds , coordinator will return failure, but that one node will not rollback, so you need a consistency level of 5 in order to achieve strong consistentcy

The documentation has conflicting information

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find much in the official documentation to support my point as concrete evidence, due to lack of detail on the full write path, but I can share my 2 cents on the topic.

I think I understand where you see the gap in consistency.

First let's establish that when a client reads with consistency level (CL) of `LOCAL_QUORUM` with replication factor (RF) 5, the Cassandra coordinator for that request will only contact 3 Cassandra replicas for a read (out of 5) - 1 to return the actual data to the coordinator, and the other 2 to return a digest of the data for a consistency check.

However, when a client writes with CL `LOCAL_QUORUM` against the same keyspace, the Cassandra coordinator will send the mutation **to all reachable replicas**.
What the CL for mutations implies, in this example `LOCAL_QUORUM`, is that 3 replicas must succeed in completing the write request locally within the write timeout period (default 2 sec).

In other words if the coordinator doesn't receive an acknowledged write from at least 3 replicas within 2 seconds, the write is reported as failed to the client. Although in the background the coordinator will attempt to replicate it to all replicas in the cluster, with no rollbacks. If you have repairs running and tuned to [`gc_grace_seconds`](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/compaction/index.html#the-gc_grace_seconds-parameter-and-tombstone-removal), eventually all 5 replicas will be consistent.

If a replica is unavailable, the coordinators can store write requests in the form of [hints](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/hints.html) for a default period of 3h. As soon as unreachable nodes are back up, if hints didn't expire yet, the coordinator will send the previously failed mutations.

It should be noted that unreachable nodes will miss mutations past the 3h hint window. Then there are 2 possible ways to retrieve dropped mutations on previously unreachable nodes:

- [Read Repairs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/operating/read_repair.html) (passive) - If a coordinator detects a digest mismatch during a read with CL > 1, it will repair the mismatched data before returning the results to the client, in what's called a blocking read repair.
- [Anti-entropy Repairs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.1/cassandra/operating/repair.html) (active) - Repairs are an essential operation in live Cassandra clusters that actively scan, hash, and compare ranges of data between replicas, encompassing the full dataset, and repair the data via streaming whenever inconsistencies are found.